# Extreme learning machines in R for discrete attributes

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to run the following example of ELM in R on famous Titanic dataset:

```
library(elmNN)
dataset <- read.csv(training_data)
formula <- as.factor(Survived) ~ Sex + Age + Pclass + Fare + SibSp + Parch + Embarked
elm_fit <- elmtrain(formula, dataset, nhid=10, actfun="sig")
testset$PredSurvived <- predict(elm_fit, testset, type="class")
```

The training method throws me the following error:

```
Error in ginv(t(H), tol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) %*% t(T) : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

As I understand, this is because the algorithm is expecting numeric data, while my attributes are discrete.

My question is that is there a way to apply this algorithm on my data set?

Comment: Coerce all your columns to numeric?

Comment: Won't work, because the algorithm internally multiplies matrices of numeric data. I was wondering if there exists a variation for this algorithm that accepts discrete data.

Answer (score 1):

translate factors to binary representation using model.matrix. For instance, Species in iris can be generated as model.matrix( ~ Species, data=iris)